# Scaleratio plotly

Tags: python, plotly-python

There is a solution to the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, sin, cos
import plotly.graph_objects as go


def degree2rad(degrees):
    return degrees * pi / 180


def disk_part(center, radius, start_angle, end_angle, n_points=50):
    t = np.linspace(degree2rad(start_angle), degree2rad(end_angle), n_points)
    x = center[0] + radius * cos(t)
    y = center[1] + radius * sin(t)
    return np.append(x, (center[0], x[0])), np.append(y, (center[1], y[0]))


x_points = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_points = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ab = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [3, 7], [15, 2]]
radius = 0.4
colors = ["yellow", "red"]

fig = go.Figure()

for x, y, (a, b) in zip(x_points, y_points, ab):
    ratio = a / (a + b)
    for start_angle, end_angle, color in zip(
        (0, 360 * ratio), (360 * ratio, 359.9), colors
    ):
        x_disk, y_disk = disk_part([x, y], radius, start_angle, end_angle)
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=x_disk,
                y=y_disk,
                fill="toself",
                fillcolor=color,
                line={"color": color},
                name=f"{(end_angle-start_angle)/360 * 100:.1f}%",
            )
        )

fig.update_yaxes(scaleanchor="x", scaleratio=1)
fig.show()
```

The output satisfies the problem, but with x_points = [0.39, 0.17, 0.12, 1.2] and y_points = [210, 160, 150, 250]the output is unreadable. How to select the colorscale parameter or some other solution?

I tried to normalize the axis (y_points / max(y_points). And the values on the axis are output using
tickvals, ticktext.

Comment: What do you mean "the output is unreadable"? What does "There is a solution to the problem:" mean?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what is your problem first?

Answer (score 0):

Remark: In a follow-up question, please always [link to the previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75760477/how-to-draw-multiple-pie-chart-circles-using-plotly) question to avoid confusion.

Regarding your question:

I have introduced a "scale-ratio" which now displays circles without having to expand the x- or y-axis into "unreadable" regimes:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, sin, cos
import plotly.graph_objects as go


def degree2rad(degrees):
    return degrees * pi / 180


def disk_part(center, radius, start_angle, end_angle, scale_ratio, n_points=50):
    t = np.linspace(degree2rad(start_angle), degree2rad(end_angle), n_points)
    x = center[0] + radius * cos(t) * scale_ratio
    y = center[1] + radius * sin(t)
    return np.append(x, (center[0], x[0])), np.append(y, (center[1], y[0]))


x_points = [0.39, 0.17, 0.12, 1.2]
y_points =  [210, 160, 150, 250]
ab = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [3, 7], [15, 2]]
radius = 5
colors = ["yellow", "red"]

fig = go.Figure()
x_range = (max(x_points) - min(x_points))
y_range = (max(y_points) - min(x_points))
scale_ratio = x_range/y_range

for x, y, (a, b) in zip(x_points, y_points, ab):
    ratio = a / (a + b)
    for start_angle, end_angle, color in zip(
        (0, 360 * ratio), (360 * ratio, 359.9), colors
    ):
        x_disk, y_disk = disk_part([x, y], radius, start_angle, end_angle, scale_ratio)
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=x_disk,
                y=y_disk,
                fill="toself",
                fillcolor=color,
                line={"color": color},
                name=f"{(end_angle-start_angle)/360 * 100:.1f}%",
            )
        )

fig.show()
```